# A kind of lookup table to calculate values depending on input value

Tags: javascript

I would like to create a table with different value. Those values are calculated depending on an input value.

For example, if the input is '30', the first line of the table is '30cm'. The second line gets the value 'small', as it is <100. The third line is just the half value, which is a simple calculation:

```
Line 1: 30cm
Line 2: small
Line 3: 15
```

If input is '200', the line 2 is 'big' (>100):

```
Line 1: 200cm
Line 2: big
Line 3: 100
```

If input is '1000', the line 2 is 'huge' (>500):

```
Line 1: 1000cm
Line 2: huge
Line 3: 500
```

There are multiple lines and multiple calculated values like shown above.

My question in which way I could create a kind of 'lookup table' from where the data comes from. I didn't get it using an object or an array.
Line 3 is easy as it just takes a `value / 2`, but how do I get `small`, `big` or `huge` for values <100 or >500.

There may are be more different ranges used for a line value...

Comment: `but how do I get small, big or huge for values <100 or >500.` IF statements ? and if not Please provide us with more to work with

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using an array for a lookup table of his sort would work just fine, and is pretty elegant. For example:

```js
const lookup = [{
  size: 0, // smallest possible
  name: 'small',
},{
  size: 100, // larger than 100
  name: 'big',
}, {
  size: 500,
  name: 'huge',
}].reverse(); // note the reverse
function getLines(input) {
  const { name } = lookup.find(({ size }) => input > size);
  return [input, name, input / 2];
}
console.log(getLines(30));
console.log(getLines(200));
```

Comment: Shouldn't sizes in lookup array be in descending order?

Comment: @user3142695 By listing the items in `size` order and reversing it, the first item found by `find` will be the item whose `size` is the highest possible while not being more than the `input`. So, an input of `200` would match the first descending `size`. (500 is too large, the next iteration testing 100 will pass, resulting in `big`)